# getting 500 internal server error?

Tags: php, server

Here is the php code that created the problem

```
<?php
$link = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$link_array = explode('/',$link);
$last_part = end($link_array);
if($last_part == "funnyprank01.php"||$last_part == "funnyprank02.php"||$last_part == "funnyprank03.php"||$last_part == "funnyprank04.php")
{
<meta property="og:image"            content="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/3uRpVGkVhVI/hqdefault.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type"       content="image/jpg">
}
else
{
<meta property="og:image"            content="http://www.8mags.com/images/youtubeimage.png">
<meta property="og:image:type"       content="image/png">
}
?>
```

before adding this code everything was working fine. The name of file containing this code is header.php

Comment: You need to close the PHP tags before you output raw content.

Comment: so after the if part I should put closing ?> and then for else part start it again?

Comment: Your edit looks correct, please advise if you are receiving an additional error.

Comment: No, it is working fine now. Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this resolved by selecting an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$link = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$link_array = explode('/',$link);
$last_part = end($link_array);
if($last_part == "funnyprank01.php"||$last_part == "funnyprank02.php"||$last_part ==     "funnyprank03.php"||$last_part == "funnyprank04.php")
{
?>
<meta property="og:image"            content="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/3uRpVGkVhVI/hqdefault.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type"       content="image/jpg">
<?php
}
else
{
?>
<meta property="og:image"            content="http://www.8mags.com/images/youtubeimage.png">
<meta property="og:image:type"       content="image/png">
<?php
}
?>
```

If it STILL returns a 500 error, refer to my original answer

Comment: I got a minus 1 and you got a minus 1. No one knows why?

Comment: I know why, see the comment under your question. I blatantly missed that.

Comment: I am editing the code to show what it should be like. Please correct me if I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to close php tags.

```
<?php
$link = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$link_array = explode('/',$link);
$last_part = end($link_array);
if($last_part == "funnyprank01.php"||$last_part == "funnyprank02.php"||$last_part == "funnyprank03.php"||$last_part == "funnyprank04.php"):?>
<meta property="og:image"            content="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/3uRpVGkVhVI/hqdefault.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type"       content="image/jpg">
<?php else:?>
<meta property="og:image"            content="http://www.8mags.com/images/youtubeimage.png">
<meta property="og:image:type"       content="image/png">
<?php endif?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
<?php
$link = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$link_array = explode('/',$link);
$last_part = end($link_array);
if($last_part == "funnyprank01.php"||$last_part == "funnyprank02.php"||$last_part == "funnyprank03.php"||$last_part == "funnyprank04.php")
{ ?>
<meta property="og:image"            content="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/3uRpVGkVhVI/hqdefault.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type"       content="image/jpg">

<?php }
else
{ ?>
<meta property="og:image"            content="http://www.8mags.com/images/youtubeimage.png">
<meta property="og:image:type"       content="image/png">
<?php } ?>
```